# Vuetify v-intersect in Nuxt app fires before enters view

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js, intersection-observer

I have a page with the following layout:

```js
<template>
  <v-container fluid class='pa-0 ma-0 assignment-container'>
    <v-row class='pa-0 ma-0 gallery-bg'>
      // ...v-img with height 60vh
    </v-row>
    <v-row class='pa-3'>
      // ...row content
    </v-row>
    <v-row class='pa-3'>
      // ... row content
    </v-row>
    <v-row
      v-if='!works.length'
      v-intersect='onIntersect'
      class='pa-3 mt-4 flex-column'>
      <v-row class='pa-3 ma-0'>
        <h3 class='mb-4 acumin-semibold section-title section-title-h3'>
          Works:
        </h3>
      </v-row>
      <v-row class='pa-0 ma-0'>
        <v-col
          v-for='(skeleton, i) in skeletonCards'
          :key='i'
          xs='12'
          sm='6'
          md='4'
          lg='3'>
          <v-skeleton-loader
            class='mx-auto'
            max-width='374'
            height='250'
            type='card' />
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-row>
    <v-container v-else fluid>
      <v-row class='pa-3 ma-0'>
        <h3 class='mb-4 acumin-semibold section-title section-title-h3'>
          Works:
        </h3>
      </v-row>
      <v-row class='pa-0 ma-0'>
        <v-col
          v-for='work in works'
          :key='work._id'
          xs='12'
          sm='6'
          md='4'
          lg='3'>
          <WorkCard :assignment-id='$route.params.id' :work='work' />
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  // ...all the imports

  export default {
    components: {WorkCard, UIButton},
    async asyncData(context) {
      // ... fetch and return assignment
    },
    data() {
      return {
        works: []
      }
    },
    computed: {
      skeletonCards() {
        return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.lg ? 4 : 3
      }
    },
    methods: {
      async fetchWorks() {
        this.works = await this.$nuxt.context.app.apolloProvider.defaultClient.query({
          query: worksByAssignmentIdQuery,
          variables: {
            id: this.$nuxt.context.route.params.id,
          }
        })
          .then(({data}) => data.assignmentWorks)
          .catch(err => console.error(err))
      },
      onIntersect() {
        console.log('intersect fired')
        this.fetchWorks()
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

The problem is that v-intersect directive fires even when it's not in the view yet.

I tried to define threshold:

```
v-intersect='{
    handler: onIntersect,
    options: {
      threshold: [1.0]
    }
  }'
```

And it keeps firing.

Then I thought maybe it's because it's rendered on the server, so I tried to wrap this part of markup in `<client-side>` element. Still firing. I tried to wrap the entire page in that element, tried to put an empty `<p>` element after all the rest and apply that directive on it - and it still fired.

I had the fetching part inside `fetch()` method with `fetchOnServer` set to `false` and I called `this.$fetch()` in my `onIntersect` method. And it kept firing every time. As if this row is always in the view, even though it is not.

I ran out of ideas... Any help, please?

Answer (score 2):

OK, looks like I finally solved it. First of, apparently you can't place the v-intersect directive on a v-row element.

So I created an invisible div element with 0px width and height, on which I applied the v-intersect directive:

```
...
<div
  v-intersect='{
    handler: onIntersect,
    options: {
      threshold: [1.0]
    }
  }'
  class='invisible' />
...

<style scoped>
  .invisible {
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
   }
<style>
```

Thein in my `onIntersect` method I'm passing `isIntersecting` parameter, and invoking the `fetchWorks` method if it's true:

```
onIntersect(entries, observer, isIntersecting) {
  if (isIntersecting) {
    this.fetchWorks()
  }
}
```

Now it intersects correctly and fetching data when the view (div) is in viewport (even though it's invisible), whether when scrolled there or the page was refreshed on that pixel.

Since I'll need to use v-intersect in other parts of my project, I'm considering turning this div into a component, to which I'll pass the intersect callback function.

Comment: Thanks for this solution :) do you mind sharing your full component code?  Thanks again